# cannot open WD 1TB Hard

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I Cannot open my hard drive.

When i plug it to any PC the hard appears as this picture

[image]

then i opened the computer manager the hard drive appears as this picture

[image]

I cannot open the drive or recover it with any application.

also i cannot open it in Ubuntu

Comment: Which drive letter is it in the screenshot? What happens when you double click the icon?

Comment: drive letter is H, when i open it, the window loading forever.

Comment: Have you partitioned and formatted the disk ?

Comment: the hard drive contains data that i need it :/

Comment: If this is an external HDD try using it on a different computer. Also make sure to check the HDD health status. You can  use [WD DLG](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=jUZqV1) that is the WD HDD testing tool. Try only the Quick test first, before you make sure the HDD is in good health you should restrain from any excessive attempts to read the HDD because in case of drive failure this could cause additional damage to the data.